# How to collect elements of each position in brackets and write them in the csv file in python

Tags: python, pandas

```
   {1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{10,11,12}...
```

I have the above set of brackets. All I want to do is, write each column in the csv file with those valuse in brackets.

```
a   b   c
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9
10  11  12
```

This is what I want to get in csv. I looked for normal distribution equations and how to switch to dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["asdf(q3de(18)), ( england 2020 )", 2, 3],
                ["aecf(bwe(34))/ ( korea( 2020 ))", 2, 3],
                ["nwvf(bsde(6g)) - (china(2020)", 2, 3]],
                columns = ["brand", "height", "weight"])

for i in range(len(df)):
   df['brand'][i] = re.sub(regex, '', df['brand'][i])
   print(df['brand'][i])

#this prints like this
print(df)
'''
   brand height  weight
0  asdf    2      3
1  aecf    2      3
2  nwvf    2      3
```

Some of the information I found is the same way as above. But as I intended, I don't have a sense of how to call the order of certain positions in brackets. If it was a list, I could have used [0], [1], etc., but this case is different because I used curly brackets. I don't know how to deal with the position for brackets.

Comment: You can use `split()` to make it into a list and index from there, or you can try using regex. I think `split()` is better.

Comment: can you post a sample of your actual data; before and after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach could be like this using `ast.literal_eval()`:

```py
import ast
st = "{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{10,11,12}"
st = st.replace('{', '[')
st = st.replace('}', ']')
st = list(ast.literal_eval(st))
```

This results in

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

which you can index and use easily.

Also, here just using `ast.literal_eval(st)` would return `st` as a tuple of lists like

```
([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12])
```

which is also iterable and you can avoid casting to list explicitly.